# Why doesn't the total energy in Bohr's model of the atom include the energy in the magnetic field of the electron?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics

When the electron "jumps" from a more energetic state to a less energetic state, its orbital speed increases since its kinetic energy equals $\frac{kZe^2}{2r}$ (where $k$ is Coulomb's constant, $Ze$ is the charge of the nucleus with $e$ the elementary charge, and $r$ is the orbital radius). During the "jump", then, there must be acceleration of the electron from its initial speed to its final speed and thus its magnetic field changes. Since a changing magnetic field induces an electric field that, by Lenz's law, tries to cancel the change in the electron's speed (like the back emf in starting a current in a circuit), work must be done against this electric field to increase the speed of the electron, and this energy may be regarded as being stored in the electron's magnetic field. However, in textbooks, the expression for the total energy of the atom does not contain this energy. What did I get wrong in my reasoning above?

I know Bohr's model is a limited depiction of the atom, but I don't understand why there isn't energy in the magnetic field of the electron in this model.

Comment: The Bohr model is too wrong to even try: consider the ground state of the H atom, under Bohr's model the electron has to still orbit, but in the correct quantum calculations, the ground state electron does not have any orbital angular momentum. On an unrelated note, you are also using Bohr's model wrong: You are not meant to be able to ask what happens in both the stationary parts and the transient parts of the modelling. Only that the whole transition refers to this full energy jump, and no attempt is made to explain them.

Comment: The Bohr's model doesn't try to be internally or globally consistent, it's just a first attempt to explain quantization of the emission spectrum and stability of the atom.